# The second command doesn't run as root

Tags: shell, jenkins, lxc, su

I have created a Jenkins job today, what it does is the Jenkins user should log into another server and run two commands separated by &&:

```
ssh -i /creds/jenkins jenkins@servername.com "sh -c 'sudo su && lxc exec containername bash'"
```

The logging part works fine, then it runs the `sudo su` command and becomes root but it never runs the second command.

I even did this manually and from the Jenkins machine logged into the other server (servername). Then ran `sh -c "sudo su && lxc exec containername bash"` with no luck.

Answer (score 1):

Try to execute the second command as a parameter for the `sudo su` command, like this:

```
ssh -i /creds/jenkins jenkins@servername.com "sh -c 'sudo su -c "lxc exec containername bash"'"
```

Comment: Thanks,I did what you suggestedIt thinks